# regex match string between space or symbol before first and after last chracter

Tags: javascript, regex, match

If I want to match string that has a space in start and end, I use this RegEx :

```
XRegExp('(^|\\s)('+input+')(?=\\s|$)',"g");
```

Example:

```
 " this is my string between spaces "
```

This will match any string that start and end with space, but I also want to match any string that starts and ends with symbols.

Example:

```
"{this is my string between brackets}"
```

So, basically I need RegEx to find string between spaces or symbols.

Comment: this? `XRegExp('(^|[{\\s])('+input+')(?=[}\\s]|$)',"g");`

Comment: my bad silly question but i was needed thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your symbols are reserved operators, you need to escape them:

```
^([ \t\{\[\(])(.*?)([ \t\}\]\)])$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\W+(.*?)\W+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  this regex for all special character including '_' (underscore)

```
^(\W|_)(.*?)(\W|_)$
```